# Use container name or id as environment variable in docker compose yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I use the container's name or ID as env variable in `docker-compose.yml`?

I tried multiple ways (no one is good):

```
environment:
  SERVER_NAME: "${SERVER_NAME}"
  SERVER_NAME: container_name
  SERVER_NAME: {{container_name}}
  SERVER_NAME: "${container_name}"
  SERVER_NAME: "{{.Host.Hostname}}"
  SERVER_NAME: "{{.Container.external_id}}"
  SERVER_NAME: "{{.Container.External_id}}"
  SERVER_NAME: "${HOSTNAME}"
```

SOLVED in my python code:

```
import socket
SERVER_NAME = socket.gethostname()
```

Comment: I'm not sure my answer addresses your problem, please let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Why do you want this piece of information; and specifically as an environment variable?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a script (javascript + python) that sends sentry logs. I want the container's ID to be a tag in each log item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly override it, a container's **hostname**(1) is its container ID.  You can see this with a simple experiment:

```
$ docker run busybox hostname
cb8ad16c0a67
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
cb8ad16c0a67        busybox             "hostname"          3 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                       jolly_hodgkin
```

The [Sentry documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=node#server-name) suggests that this hostname will become the default value for the `serverName` configuration option, though it's worth verifying that.  You can imagine other information like the image name, tag, and server hostname that you might also want to include in error reports; these are harder for a container process to discover on its own, and you do need to push them in through environment variables or something similar, but they're also much less variable.

(In a Kubernetes context, the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) can directly inject this information as environment variables.)

Answer (score 5):

One way is setting the container name:

```
services:
  <service>:
    image: <image>
    container_name: <container_name>
    # ^ explicitly set the container's name
```

and then use it (`<container_name>`) wherever you want.